# Permutation between two array with limited items

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Suppose I have two arrays/vectors like:

```
A[4]={4,6,9,7};
B[4]={12,4,9,3};
```

I have to take exact two items from those two arrays and not will be the same index (if I take A[0], then I can't take B[0]) and the sum of that combination will be minimum.

Suppose,

```
From A we took, A[0] and A[2]
From B we took, B[1] and B[3]
```

Then it will give me the minimum result: `20`

How can I solve it with `next_permutation`?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following to iterate over disjoinct pair of A and B:

```
enum E { A, B, None };

std::vector<E> es {E::A, E::A, E::B, E::B};
es.resize(a.size(), E::None); // es is sorted

do {
    std::cout << "checking:";
    int index = -1;
    for (auto e : es) {
         ++index;
         switch (e) {
             case E::A: std::cout << " A :" << index;
             case E::B: std::cout << " B :" << index;
         }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
} while (std::next_permutation(es.begin(), es.end()));
```